# How can I write a query?

Tags: python, elasticsearch, elasticsearch-5

```
"search_id" : "7f2d683165",
          "uploaded_time" : "2019-05-10 15:25:35.373",
          "processing_end_time" : "2019-05-10 15:25:38.115",
          "batches" : {
            "5cd598617026837753891a2b" : {
              "is_reviewed" : false,
              "batch_name" : "T--45"
            }
          }
```

How can I write correct query for if i want`("is_reviewed" : true)`?
I have try this:

```
query={"query": { "nested" : {"path" : "batches","query" : {"bool" : {"should" : [ { "match" : {"batches.is_reviewed" : true} }]}}}}}

res=es.search(index="cool",body={"query":{"match":{"pass":"true"}}})
```

**I want output only `"pass:true"`**.

Comment: Are you sure that `batches` is of `nested` type?

Answer (score 0):

You can either try this:

```
{
  "query": {
    "query_string": {
      "query": "batches.\\*.is_reviewed:true"
    }
  }
}
```

or this if `batches` is `nested`:

```
{
  "query": {
    "nested": {
      "path": "batches",
      "query": {
        "bool": {
          "should": [
            {
              "query_string": {
                "query": "batches.\\*.is_reviewed:true"
              }
            }
          ]
        }
      }
    }
  }
}
```

Comment: I've modified the queries, try to see if it works. You should rethink your data design though, as you might end up creating way too many fields in your index.

Comment: Sorry, the `*` needs to be escaped, try again.

Comment: it works on my end. Please make sure to type exactly what I've shown

Comment: You have used forward slashes instead of backward slashes. Just copy/paste my query

Comment: If you're running it through Python, try with a single backslash, not two

Comment: What client/language are you using?

Comment: i have use windows 10,python

Comment: hello can you tell me whrere's the mistek ?